# What does cracking a Diffie-Hellman prime number mean?

Tags: primes, diffie-hellman

I am doing a project on the Diffie-Hellman key exchange and this isn't necessary for my project but I am very interested in how you 'crack' a prime number.

Comment: A very quick Google search resulted in... http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/maths-experts-stunned-as-they-crack-a-pattern-for-prime-numbers-a6933156.html

Comment: How does a pattern of the sequence of prime numbers constitute cracking a prime number?  I am more interested in how a prime number is 'cracked' and what it actually means to be 'cracked'.

Comment: The point was to show that I spent about as much time researching the answer as you did in formulating the question, which if you would have read the "how to ask a question" section would know that it doesn't belong here in this forum.  Try the StackExchange Math forum instead.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You crack a Diffie-Hellman semi-prime by factoring it into its two constituent prime factors. The security of Diffie-Hellman comes from the fact that it is not possible, with current technology, to factor semi-primes of the size that are used in cryptography.